# Selenium Python - encoding german special characters

Tags: python, selenium

Do you ever meet this kind of problem?
My selenium-python script starts from;

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

but despite this script has a problem with reading special german characters. By the way it happens also with special characters of another languages.

Comment: What kind of "problem"? Show the code and any error, and specify which version of Python you are using. Note that comments like that affect only literal characters within the script itself.

Comment: I use Python 2.7. Instead of Ä I recive in a console \\xc3\\xa4, instead of Ü  \\xc3\\xbc

Comment: But you need to *show the code* that gets and displays that data.

Comment: try: self.assertEqual("ä", driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").text)
 except AssertionError as e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))

Comment: Firstly, put that code in the question. Secondly, why are you doing this? Why raise an exception only to catch it? Why then stringify the exception, rather than logging the actual data?

Comment: Removing exept Assertion Error line seems to solve the problem. Script still asserts  the text and without problem with special characters. Thanks.

Comment: But when I use pure Python, without unittest framework, problem remains:                                                                                   
     element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
      assert element2.text == 'Ö'    So it's impossible to assert german special characters at all.

Comment: Please update your question body with the code you’re running and the full output, including error message and stacktrace.